# Pasar variable de un archivo a otro

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero poder pasar el nombre de usuario al momento de hacer login para poder usarlo en otra pagina.

Intente obtenerla guardándola en `$_SESSION['username']` pero el problema es que también guardo un contador en otra variable de sesión para que cada 2 horas que el usuario pase en el sistema tenga que iniciar sesión de nuevo y cuando el tiempo se termina los textos donde uso las variables de sesión desaparecen, pero vuelven a aparecer cuando el usuario vuelve a iniciar sesion.

También intente usar `include 'checklogin.php'` (que es donde recibo la variable) pero otro problema es que ese archivo también imprime un texto donde le indica al usuario si introdujo datos incorrectos y cuando lo llamo en la pagina donde esta el bloqueo de sesión se imprime ese texto.

Solo necesito pasar el nombre del usuario.

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de lo que haz intentado hasta ahora, para que sea más fácil el poder ayudarte, puedes utilizar otra alternativa con **JavaScript**, puedes usar `LocalStorage` para guardar el nombre de usuario en el navegador.

Comment: Aqui esta el codigo https://jsfiddle.net/a8vhgpnq/

Comment: `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['user'] = $username;`
no estás sobre-escribiendo la misma variable?

Comment: Oh, gracias por la correccion, pero eso no afecta. El problema viene cuando la variable `$_SESSION['expire']` llega a 0, ya que donde sea que imprima los valores que tengo en las variables de sesion desaparecen.

Comment: Qué validación haces cuando `$_SESSION['expire']` llega a 0? destruyes la sesión?

Comment: `$now = time();
 if($now > $_SESSION['expire']) {
  header("Location: lockscreen.php");
  exit;
 }`

Comment: Por qué validas con la variable `$now` si ya guardaste la hora en la variable de sesión `$_SESSION['start'] = time();`, cuando ya hayan pasado 2 horas, deberías de re-direccionar a un archivo que destruya la sesión y que lo mande al inicio para que vuelva a entrar, estás iniciando en todos tus archivos con `session_start()`? para que puedas usar esa variable en cualquier página a la que redirecciones.